# Active Record Querying belong_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have the two following models associated:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :language
end

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

From a view I have a link to filter the posts by language:

```
<div id="english"><%= link_to "English", {:controller => 'posts', :action => 'search_result', :language => "english"} %></div>
```

The model language has a variable name:string which is the one i am using to make the active record query.

The doubt i have is how i can make this query from the post controller to retrieve the right posts which has a field: language.name == "english".

I tried this:

```
@posts = Post.all(:conditions => ["language.name = ?", params[:language]])
```

and also this:

```
@posts = Post.where(:language.name => params[:language])
```

Hope i have explained well the issue, i am a quite newbie yet. Ah! i would also know what would it be better in this case to use: "all" or "where" ??. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a join: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables

If I have understood your models/database structure correctly, the ActiveRecord call should looks something like:

```
Post.joins(:language).where('languages.name' => params[:language])
```

Hope that helps.

PS. The `where` call is the preferred method these days.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question cause I messed up spanish and english and where i wrote idioma i should have written language. I tried with joins and still no luck. The model Post belongs to Language and Language has a field called name. So i tried  Post.joins(:language).where('language.name' => params[:language]) but it gives me an error: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: language.name.  Maybe the confusion is that a language has_many posts and not the opossite.. i'll keep trying! thanks for your answer.. i should get it working using joins.

Comment: In the where clause you need to use the actual table name, so you should try: `Post.joins(:language).where('languages.name' => params[:language])`

Comment: @salt.racer @Adnan: No, it doesn't work, i have already tried that and i get:  `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: language.name: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "languages" ON "languages"."id" = "posts"."language_id" WHERE "language"."name" = 'english'`... This would work for sure if Post has_many languages (i checked it) but not if Post belongs_to Language. Still stuck on this, any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I have a similar model and I have successfully used this (Im changing the model names for you): `Post.joins(:language).where(:languages => {:name => params[:language]})` Can you try that?

Comment: @Adnan @salt.racer it worked! I was stupid i didn't realize about the 's' in your first answer and in the answer of Salt.racer. I was trying with: `Post.joins(:language).where(:language => {:name => params[:language]})` without the 's'. now its working and it work as you said in the first commment and in this last comment, both are equivalent!. Thanks a lot to you both.

Comment: There are indeed both equivalent. I prefer the method in my second comment as it visually separates the conditions applied to the joined table from those applied to the parent table. Looks cleaner (to me anyway). Glad to be of help!